# How can I see the python actions in Blender

Tags: python

Is there a way to see the python code generated when I do actions? I know that this may be a simple question but I just started using blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by dragging the top menu bar downwards and you’ll see the python code there as shown in the top of the snapshot below.

[image]